# Linear layout weightsum property is not working with Layout_height in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My app has a textview and it's height should be adjusted according to weight property, but its giving red error.

code is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <TextView
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/hello_pleasse_login"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MATYw.png)

I have tried android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_height="0" also but it doesn't work,
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default linearLayout orientation is horizontal
Change it to the vertical
`android:orientation="vertical"`

Now, you will not get the error

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:orientation="vertical"` to parent layout . The default Orientation for `LinearLayout` is `Horizontal`.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">
<TextView
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="@string/hello_pleasse_login"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```